# Netflix: Is there an app yet?

Tags: streaming, television, netflix

Is there an app to play videos from Netflix and Hulu for the Android?

Comment: Do you mean a single app that plays can play both /either Netflix and Hulu? If not, then let's edit this to omit the Hulu double-barrel question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes there is**!

Today Netflix released an [offical App](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.netflix.mediaclient&feature=search_result).

[Netflix Blog post](http://blog.netflix.com/2011/05/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none.html) about release.

Currently Netflix playback is supported on the following phones:

- HTC Incredible with Android 2.2
- HTC Nexus One with Android 2.2, 2.3
- HTC Evo 4G with Android 2.2
- HTC G2 with Android 2.2
- Samsung Nexus S with Android 2.3

If you don't have one of these devices but you do have an HTC or Samsung device you can try [this method here](http://lifehacker.com/5801720/how-to-install-netflix-on-almost-any-android-device) to make the Netflix app work on your device.  I have not tried this myself as I have one of the supported devices.  Try this at your own risk

Comment: More recently, Netflix said it works on all phones that run Android 2.2 and 2.3.

Answer (score 5):

Netflix recently posted on their blog that they will begin to roll out support for individual devices in the coming year, but not a generic Netflix app. They claim:

> The hurdle has been the lack of a generic and complete platform security and content protection mechanism available for Android.

You can read the entire post at http://blog.netflix.com/2010/11/netflix-on-android.html .

Answer (score 4):

As of today, no there is nothing public. Like Matt says, you can find this out through other sites instead of asking here. A simple Google search will give you results of speculation and rumor like this:

http://mashable.com/2010/08/07/netflix-android-app/

Answer (score 3):

No, as of Sept. 18, 2010, but according to this story Netflix appears to have hired Android developers, almost certainly for this purpose: http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/08/10/netflix-android-app/